# Thread Interrupts from a different function

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently starting a new Thread and attempting to interrupt it from another function. Like so

```
public static void simulate(ActionEvent e){ //Runs the Simulation in a new thread, allowing for realtime updating of the Textarea
    Simulate simulation = new Simulate(0.1, Main.house);
    Thread simThread = new Thread(simulation.simulate()) {};
    simThread.start();

}

public static void pause(ActionEvent e){
    simThread.interrupt();

}
```

However, simThread inside pause is of course undefined. I attempted extracting the initialization for simulation and simThread outside of the functions and making them public. But this resulted in a null pointer exception when attempting to start simThread.

Any help on how to share the thread across functions, or how to work around this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's `Simulate`? an you provide the class?

Comment: The code runs fine for me without any errors, I'm sure you are getting a null on Simulate

Comment: You're declaring a local variable `simThread` in `simulate` whatever the variable that is referenced in `pause`, it is not the one that is set in `simulate`.

Comment: @MauricePerry I know i stated that in the bottom part of my question.

Comment: @Rab This is the exception. 
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at Simulate.lambda$simulate$0(Simulate.java:34) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Yes you see It's inside Simulate.

Comment: Edit your question with the Simulate class.

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile this code, I assume that you have declared somewhere a `simThread` static variable.

Obviously, you could initialize that static variable in `simulate` by just not redeclaring it:

```
public static void simulate(ActionEvent e){ //Runs the Simulation in a new thread, allowing for realtime updating of the Textarea
    Simulate simulation = new Simulate(0.1, Main.house);
    simThread = new Thread(simulation.simulate()) {};
    simThread.start();

}
```

but you must make sure that:

1. `simulate` is always called before `pause`, and
2. `simulate` is not called twice without a `pause` in between.

You could ensure these conditions like so:

```
public static synchronized void simulate(ActionEvent e){ //Runs the Simulation in a new thread, allowing for realtime updating of the Textarea
    if (simThread != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("A simulation is already running.");
    }
    Simulate simulation = new Simulate(0.1, Main.house);
    simThread = new Thread(simulation.simulate()) {};
    simThread.start();
}

public static synchronized void pause(ActionEvent e){
    if (simThread == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Simulation is not running.");
    }
    simThread.interrupt();
    simThread = null;
}
```

Comment: Note that i have also make the methods synchronized in case they were not called by the same thread.

Comment: Thanks, simulate() is always called before pause() though. I have fixed the original problem, but now the thread throws an exception when being interrupted. Specifically 
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.Error: Interrupted attempt to acquire write lock

Comment: @JackBonnnell is it catching the InterruptedException?

Comment: While the code is correct, this is a very bad way of solving the problem from an architecturally perspective and should not be implemented like this. Rule of thumb: if you use `synchronized` you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many mistakes in the code presented, that I have to start a few steps earlier to answer the question properly.

**1. Which Thread constructor are you using?**

Thread offers several constructors that take Strings, Runnables or Threadgroups as arguments. Your function constructs the thread with the result of `simulation.simulate()` which has to be one of the above return types to be able to compile. I am pretty sure you do not realize that at this point the entire `simulate` function is running and completed before the thread is even started. Also notice that you then define the abstract Thread class with an empty implementation (the `{ }`).

Try initializing the Thread like this:

```
final Simulate simulation = new Simulate(0.1, Main.house);
Thread simThread = new Thread(simulation::simulate);
```

This will pass the method `simulate` itself as a `Runnable` parameter to the Thread constructor. Note that for this to work, the simulate method must be of return-type `void`.

**2. How is the external function supposed to access the local variable?**

In your method you declare a variable visible only to the method itself. How is any external code supposed to address it? You need at minimum to return the local variable (and therefore making it public):

```
public static Thread simulate(ActionEvent e){
  final Simulate simulation = new Simulate(0.1, Main.house);
  final Thread simThread = new Thread(simulation::simulate);
  simThread.start();
  return simThread;
}
```

Now an external caller will receive the Thread that has been created and can then afterwards interrupt it `theReturnedValue.interrupt()`

Alternatively you can assign ids to the Threads you create and manage them internally, but this would be out of scope for this answer.

**3. What do you think `interrupt` does?**

There is no (legal) way of stopping a thread from running, so the only thing that `interrupt` does is to send a "request" to the thread to stop working. Since you have not posted the `simulate` method I can only guess what happens there.

`interrupt` will cause all blocking operations to suddenly continue and set the interrupted-flag on the current thread, which will usually cause an `InterruptedException` to be thrown. You can either react to that or checkt he `Thread.interrupted` method, which will return true if the interrupt flag of *the Thread calling that function* has been set by someone (which should be the Thread you created in your case).

**Further reading**

For your case the [FutureTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) has been creased and should be used. It requires an [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--) to run the actual task.

Comment: Why do you say final is required?

Comment: You are correct, it is not in this case. However it is good practice to use it.